# ReferenceError: context is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a sendNotification function by using node.js and firebase function but unfortunately I am currently stuck. I never got a notification from the sender and when I look to Firebase function logs, I saw an error says

```
ReferenceError: context is not defined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:9:32)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

this is my code index.js code

```
`const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('notifications/{user_id}').onWrite(event => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have notification from: ', user_id);

if (!event.val()) {
    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database: ', notification_id);
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return fromUser.then(result => {

    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Friend Request",
            body: "You've received a Friend Request",
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id , payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification feature');

    });

});

});
```

I don't know where is the error here can someone tell me where is the error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says - you never define `context` before you use it...?

Comment: Okay, so how can I define the context here?

Comment: I don't know, it's your app - you seem to have something in mind when you access its `.params.user_id`. Figure out what that object is, and assign it to `context` before you use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('notifications/{user_id}').onWrite((change,context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;

});
```

`onWrite` has two parameters `change` and `context`. You use `context` to access the wildcards example `user_id`.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved my own problem by the help of @PeterHaddad. I read the link that he post and I change some of my code. Here it is

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('notifications/{user_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have notification from: ', user_id);

if (!change.after.val()) {
    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database: ', notification_id);
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return fromUser.then(result => {

    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Friend Request",
            body: "You've received a Friend Request",
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id , payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification feature');

    });

});

});
```